# Significant location changes in iOs 4.2 in background

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have the following code in my appDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions (NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
  m_manager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
  NSLog(@"Significant Location Change Available: %d", [CLLocationManager significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable]);
  [m_manager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
  [window addSubview:viewController.view];
  [window makeKeyAndVisible];

  m_manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
  m_manager.delegate = self; 
  viewController.manager = m_manager;

  [UIDevice currentDevice].batteryMonitoringEnabled = YES;
  return YES;
}
```

And this is my delegate callback:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
  viewController.locationInfo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your current position:\nLatitude: %f\nLongitude: %f\nBattery: %f",
                                  newLocation.coordinate.latitude,
                                  newLocation.coordinate.longitude,
                                  [UIDevice currentDevice].batteryLevel];

  ASIFormDataRequest *req = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver.com/location"]];
  [req setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
  [req addPostValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:newLocation.coordinate.latitude] forKey:@"latitude"];
  [req addPostValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:newLocation.coordinate.longitude] forKey:@"longitude"];
  [req addPostValue:[UIDevice currentDevice].uniqueIdentifier forKey:@"deviceid"];
  [req addPostValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:[self.viewController.statusSwitch isOn]] forKey:@"gps"];
  if ([UIDevice currentDevice].batteryState != UIDeviceBatteryStateCharging &&
  [UIDevice currentDevice].batteryLevel > 0)
    [req addPostValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[UIDevice currentDevice].batteryLevel] forKey:@"battery"];

  if (viewController.manualUpdate) {
    req.delegate = self;
    req.didReceiveResponseHeadersSelector = @selector(didReceiveResponse:);
  }
  [req startAsynchronous];

  UILocalNotification* alarm = [[[UILocalNotification alloc] init] autorelease];
  if (alarm)
  {
    alarm.fireDate = [NSDate date];
    alarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    alarm.repeatInterval = 0;
    alarm.alertBody = @"Received location delegate";

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:alarm];
  }
}
```

My problem is with activating my GPS. if I call

```
[m_manager startLocationUpdate];
```

I receive the local notification and the server gets updated. However, if I use

```
[m_manager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

I don't receive local notification.

I even took a 10 min drive on the highway to test the notification and got nothing... 
Anyone has got that thing working under iOS 4.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MLefrancois's answer should address your main problem. The other issue is that significant-location-change notifications are currently really coarse: you get a notification when your phone gets handed off from one cell tower to another, and that's about it. Region monitoring works the same way.

Comment: For the typos, I answered MLefrancois. As for the rest, you're basically saying that within 10 kms it's possible that I don't receive any update from the manager?

Comment: Possible. The area a single cell tower can cover is pretty large, especially on flat terrain. It could be some other problem, though.

Comment: That would make sense, since I have received a notification the other day. Thank you.

Comment: @pier-Olivier Thibault: Can you tell me please what code you changed so that i can refer that. I am also getting same problem. Please if you have any advice tell me. I need your help.

Comment: I am not sure... This issue has been resolved a while ago. Maybe you could create a new question on SO and maybe someone could help you out?

Answer (score 2):

Any reason why you are allocating a new CLLocationManager after calling **startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges** and assigning the delegate to this other instance ?.

You might want to try this:

```
  m_manager  = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
  m_manager.delegate = self; 
  viewController.manager = m_manager;
  NSLog(@"Significant Location Change Available: %d", [CLLocationManager significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable]);
  [manager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
  [window addSubview:viewController.view];
  [window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't see this slipping through the cracks. I pasted code that was a mashup to better show my problem. It's not the actual code so it's not an actual bug ;) But thank you for pointing it out. I'll fix it